# How to unit test Connect IQ?

Tags: garmin, connectiq

Is there any support for unit testing Connect IQ applications? I could not find anything on the documentation.

Ideally, the solution should have integration with the Eclipse SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Support is added in Connect IQ SDK 2.1, where you need to
*compile* with --unit-test flag and *run* with /t flag

You must annotate your methods with (:test) and return a boolean, which would mean whether a test passed or not (true for pass).

I'm keeping this answer short at the moment. See more:
http://developer.garmin.com/blog/post/connect-iq-2-run-no-evil

Comment: There is a good article here on setting up unit tests with your Connect IQ projects: http://starttorun.info/tutorial-create-connect-iq-unit-tests/

Answer (score 2):

The documentation in the Connect IQ SDK as suggested in the other answer is not very elaborate and does not explain in detail how to do proper unit testing, it's just some simple hello world examples...

I wrote a small tutorial that explains how to write unit tests, it's a process that consists of 3 parts:

1. create test project: http://starttorun.info/tutorial-how-to-create-connect-iq-unit-test-project/
2. create run configuration: http://starttorun.info/tutorial-run-connect-iq-unit-tests/
3. create unit tests (mock/isolate/...): starttorun.info/tutorial-create-connect-iq-unit-tests/